# C2065: 'oss' undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

I use Qt Creator and I have a strange error in my C++ code. This piece of code

```
#include <stdlib.h>

std::wstring readFile(const std::wstring& f) {
    //try and open the file
    std::wifstream file(TL::wToString(f).c_str());
    if (!file)
        throw BadFileLoad(f, L"Impossible to write in the file "+f);

    //reads the content
    std::wostringstream oss;
    oss << file.rdbuf();

    return oss.str();
}
```

give this error:

> C2065: 'oss' undeclared identifier

but actually I declared it in the first line!! what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is your only error? Most likely, you already have an error in the line declaring the variable.

Comment: Are you missing some `#include` lines?

Comment: I have three errors: C2065 'oss' undeclared identifier in the line  oss << file.rdbuf(); and return oss.str(); and another in return oss.str(); C2226 left of .str must have class/struct/union

Comment: It also says that oss is a variable not used.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some include files. Try something along these lines:

```
#include <string>  // std::wstring
#include <sstream> // std::wostringstream
#include <fstream> // std::wifstream
```

Comment: sorry I had to add some more code. actually it is in a function, I edit my question.

Comment: they are already included the parent class, the IDE recognise std::wostringstream

Comment: @Colet why not post some minimal, realistic code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the header that has the class `std::wostringstream`

```
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: Apparently he gets away with this via an indirect inclusion (not portable, of course). Otherwise the definition would already be an error.

Comment: @MSalters it says undeclared identifier. I think there was an error on the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I commented this line throw BadFileLoad(f, L"Impossible to write in the file "+f); and not if (!file)...sorry guys, was a stupid quesiton! thank you for your time!